# PostgreSQL with docker ownership issue

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Since yesterday, I try to launch my docker project on Windows (Bootcamp MacBook Pro), and I have just one issue left : PostgreSQL image.

Error message :

```
postgres_1         | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1         | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1         | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1         | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1         |
postgres_1         | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1         | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1         | selecting default max_connections ... 20
postgres_1         | selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
postgres_1         | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1         | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1         | 2019-01-22 16:57:37.016 UTC [79] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
postgres_1         | 2019-01-22 16:57:37.016 UTC [79] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
postgres_1         | child process exited with exit code 1
postgres_1         | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
postgres_1         | running bootstrap script ... kibati-docker_postgres_1 exited with code 1
```

I've searched everywhere, tried everything, and still have this issue…

What I tried is :

- Create docker volume with `docker volume create --name postgres -d local` and use it in my docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  networks:
    internal_ip:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2

  volumes:
    postgres:
      external: true
```

- Add volume directly in docker compose

volume sample

```
volumes:
  postgres:
    driver: local
```

- Using relative or absolute Windows paths
- Declare multiple volumes for differents PostgreSQL folders (conf, data…)

I tried to docker compose down, restart computer, remove images, nothing change, same error.

I already checked Shared Drive box in Docker Settings.

Sources of what I've tried :

https://glennsarti.github.io/blog/puppet-in-docker/

https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-get-postgres-to-work-on-persistent-windows-mount-two-issues/12456/5

https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership/17963/28

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/435

http://www.lukaszewczak.com/2016/09/run-postgresql-using-docker-with.html

https://gdevops.gitlab.io/tuto_docker/tutoriels/postgresql/postgresql.html

https://devask.cz/questions/48645804/mount-postgres-data-to-windows-host-directory

Is anyone as a working solution ? I will continue to make it work, and update post if I found Something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having the same volume issue than in the answer for this question? https://superuser.com/questions/789754/how-to-actually-install-mediawiki-and-run-with-docker > In case of Docker images with volumes when you download the image you need to create a similar volume on your host too, because downloading a docker image doesn t download the docker volume.

Comment: It's what I've done, creating manually the volume and bind it to postgresql image in docker-compose. And it didn't worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've finally figured out what went wrong when I tried to use a volume for PostgreSQL data.

I had no idea that we used a `docker-compose.override.yml`, which declare a volume with a Windows path.

So here is a working solution to have PostgreSQL on Docker for Windows, with persisted data :

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.5
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes: 
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - pgconf:/etc/postgresql
      - pglog:/var/log/postgresql

volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
  pgconf:
    driver: local
  pglog: 
    driver: local
```

(no additional command required)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:
Run the command `docker volume create --name=pgdata`

```
   version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  networks:
    internal_ip:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2

 volumes:
   pgdata:
      external: true
```

Make sure volumes is at the same indentation level as services

Answer (score -1):

```
container_name: postgresql
image: postgres:latest
environment:
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
#    volumes:
#      - "./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data/"
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

Comment the volumes 
This work around did the trick and worked on windows, i have to bring those two lines back on mac but that's the easiest way to work for now until some real solution get pushed by docker windows or posgres docker

Comment: But this is not persistent storage volume. pg starts fresh for every boot of container.