# Cannot run or connect Portgresql container on Docker

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

In my Windows 10 machine I have a Java app and create `Postgresql` images on Docker using the following configuration:

**docker-compose.yml:***

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11

    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=demo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******
      - POSTGRES_DB=demo_test
```

And I use the following command to compose images:

```
cd postgresql
docker-compose up -d
```

Although pgadmin container is working on Docker, postgres container is generally restarting state and sometines seems to be running state for a second. When I look at that container log, I see I encounter the following errors:

*2021-03-16 09:00:18.526 UTC [82] FATAL: data directory "/data/postgres" has wrong ownership*

*2021-03-16 09:00:18.526 UTC [82] HINT: The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.*

*child process exited with exit code 1*

*initdb: removing contents of data directory "/data/postgres"

*running bootstrap script ... The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".*
*This user must also own the server process.*

I have tried to apply several workaround suggestions e.g. [PostgreSQL with docker ownership issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323348/postgresql-with-docker-ownership-issue), but none of them is working. So, how can I fix this problem?

**Update:** Here is last status of my `docker-compoese.yml` file:

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: "my-pg"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=demo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******
      - POSTGRES_DB=demo_test
    volumes:
      - psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  psql:
```

Comment: You could try and use a named volume which would also have the added effect of keeping the database in between restarts. Of course the docker user should have permissions to write to the directories you're using for those volumes.

Comment: agreed, place the data directory outside of the container with a volume, the one specified won't exist in the container.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but how? Any example pls?

Comment: @jr593 What did you agree? And **why do not post your suggestions as an answer?**

Comment: "Why do not post your suggestions as an answer?" - well, in some cases it's just an suggestion and not an answer so it might not be complete or even be the correct track (we're trying to help even if we don't have a definitive answer - at least I would do that using comments). To me a "try this" is not worth an answer since it may or may not help in your case and others that come after you might get mislead or distracted.

Answer (score 0):

As I already stated in my comment I'd suggest using a named volume.

Here's my docker-compose.yml for Postgres 12:

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:12"
    container_name: "my-pg"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "mydb"
    volumes: 
      - psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  psql:
```

Then I created the `psql` volume via `docker volume create psql` (so just a volume without any actual path mapping).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I updated my `docker-compoese.yml` file as shown on Update in my question. However, the problem still continues and I am not sure if I could create a volume using `docker volume create psql` command using PowerShell as admin. When executing `docker volume ls` command, I can observe the psql volume. But have no idea what is the problem?

Comment: Any reply please about my last comment?

Comment: @zertuc please don't get impatient. I know it can be frustrating but I have my own job as well. :) - What user is running docker? Did you install docker Desktop as admin or as another user (afaik that's the one used to run the containers). If it is another user, could you create the volume as that user instead of admin?

Comment: Sorry Thomas, yes you are right :) I do not remember which used I used, but normally I use my user (even if I do not used admin) that is already admin rights.

Comment: With ** create the volume as that user instead of admin**, do you mean to open the PowerShell by my user instead admin? If so, I tried to open PowerShell or cmd directly, but there is a indicator on the left top corner of their windows as "Administrator: ...". So, it seems to be opened as admin. But I also tried to create volume via that way and nothing is changed.

Comment: @zertuc hmm, the only thing I could think of then is the v11 container is different from the v12 I used. Could you try with v12?

Comment: I tried with v12, not working. But I am not sure if I understood correctly what you mean with the user. Do you mean that the user when I open the cmd or powershell just before creating volume?

Comment: @zertuc well, when you run the docker commands a certain system user will be used to execute those. That could be yours, an admin user or some other (I'd say it should be the one returned by the "whoami" command). If the user running Docker desktop (afaik that's the one that was used to install the application) is different from the one running the docker commands you could run into such permission issues.

Comment: But is not it weird? Because if I use admin account while executing these Docker commands, it should let that admin user to create necessary database or volumes and grant access whenever necessary. Otherwise it would be impossible to remember which user did we use before. I just a single user on my PC, myUser and administrator. myUser has already admin rights. I have tried many different things but no solution.

Comment: Would you suggest any other solution?

Comment: Yeah it is weird and I'm not sure what other solution there might be. As I said it works for me but it's hard to tell what the difference is.